# Disabling Kafka Listeners for a particular Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How to disable `@KafkaListener` instances in `@SpringBootTest` tests in applications with Spring Boot (2.2+) and Spring Kafka (2.4+)?

The goal is to disable Kafka listeners in particular tests, so that such tests can run without starting an embedded Kafka broker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot allows to exclude classes from scanning by creating custom [`TypeExcludeFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/TypeExcludeFilter.html).

To disable Kafka listeners, exclude all classes that have methods annotated with `@KafkaListener` or `@KafkaHandler`:

```
public class KafkaListenersTypeExcludeFilter extends TypeExcludeFilter {

  private static final String KAFKA_LISTENER = "org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener";
  private static final String KAFKA_HANDLER = "org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaHandler";

  @Override
  public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
    AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata = metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata();
    return annotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(KAFKA_LISTENER)
        || annotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(KAFKA_HANDLER);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null && getClass() == o.getClass();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Annotate Spring Boot test with `@TypeExcludeFilters` with `KafkaListenersTypeExcludeFilter` as a value:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TypeExcludeFilters(KafkaListenersTypeExcludeFilter.class)
public class SampleSpringBootTest {
  //...
}
```

Spring Boot tests annotated with `@TypeExcludeFilters(KafkaListenersTypeExcludeFilter.class)` will not start Kafka listeners, so do not require a Kafka broker.

When there are only a few Kafka listener beans you can also mock the listener beans as suggested [Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9959152/deadpool) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900169/disabling-kafka-listeners-for-a-particular-spring-boot-test/59900170?noredirect=1#comment105927714_59900170)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockBean({
    SampleKafkaListener.class
})
public class SampleSpringBootTest {
  //...
}
```

Comment: or you can just mock the listener bean

Comment: You can also set `autoStartup = "${auto.start:true}"` to the `@KafkaListener` and set the `auto.start` property to `false` in your tests.